# Get all the values of a ui-grid (inside each <div> of each <li>)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I actually got dynamic table made with ui-grid-b (3 columns). I got a function that generate the rows(not included but not necessary to solve) and I can remove the rows by clicking on them. My problem is, at the end of the modification of the grid, I need to get the data of the table and save it. For the moment, I don't know how to access all these datas concidering that the table is dynamic, so the number of row change and one row in the middle of others can be removed. Here is a demo of my table (with hardcoded rows, but its the code generated by a js.append() function.) : http://jsfiddle.net/xLrm2r1t/2/

```
<ul class="Table" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" style="min-width:350px">
                <li style="text-align: center !important">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </li>
                <li data-role="list-divider">
                    <div class="ui-grid-b">
                        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">Header 1</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">Header 2</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Header 3</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="addedRow">
                    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:$(this).closest('li').remove();RowCount--;">
                        <div class="ui-grid-b">
                            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">Info1</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">Info2</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Info3</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="addedRow">
                    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:$(this).closest('li').remove();RowCount--;">
                        <div class="ui-grid-b">
                            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">Info4</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">Info5</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Info6</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

For the moment, I tried many ways with the functions `.prevAll`, `.prev` and `prevUntil`, but I just don't find a good way to do it.

I just want a way to get the value inside each cell of my dynamic table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just give each element that has data you want a unique class they all share. Then simply select them all using that class, iterate over the jQuery array and grab the data you want from each.

```
<ul class="Table" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" style="min-width:350px">
                <li style="text-align: center !important">
                    <label class="has-data">Title</label>
                </li>
                <li data-role="list-divider">
                    <div class="ui-grid-b">
                        <div class="ui-block-a has-data" style="width:33%">Header 1</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b has-data" style="width:34%">Header 2</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-c has-data" style="width:33%">Header 3</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="addedRow">
                    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:$(this).closest('li').remove();RowCount--;">
                        <div class="ui-grid-b">
                            <div class="ui-block-a has-data" style="width:33%">Info1</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b has-data" style="width:34%">Info2</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-c has-data" style="width:33%">Info3</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="addedRow">
                    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:$(this).closest('li').remove();RowCount--;">
                        <div class="ui-grid-b">
                            <div class="ui-block-a has-data" style="width:33%">Info4</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b has-data" style="width:34%">Info5</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-c has-data" style="width:33%">Info6</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Then:

```
var elements = $('.has-data');
$.each(elements,
    function (index, object) {
        var value = $(object).text();
        // value now has the text content of the current element
    }
);
```

So for example HTML above the value variable would have the following values for each iteration:

Title, Header 1, Header 2, Header 3, Info1, Info2, Info3, Info4, Info5, Info6

Comment: Im not sure to get it... For example, if I want the value "Info 2", what do I do? `$('.has-data').?` (Im kinda a beginner, only doing a month im in html/javascript/php/css)

Comment: Oh sorry. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Even if I had some modification to do, it put me on the good track to find my solution. However, i had to put the class in the <ul> tag, not in the <label> to have access to all my data.